# Is there a procedure for migrating azure logic app from one account to another account

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Have two Azure accounts with different subscription, I wants to migrate azure logic app from old account to new account. Please help with the steps for migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Navigate to your logic app, In overview pane beside subscription you can find `move` from where you can migrate to another account from present.

[image]

Now you can select the destination subscription and Resource group from the  **Subscription**  list and **Resource group**  list and then select  **OK**.

**REFERENCES:**
[Move logic apps across subscriptions, resource groups, or regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/move-logic-app-resources#move-resources-between-subscriptions)

### For Cloning

**WAY - 1**
One workaround that you can try is to clone the logic app into the same subscription and resource and then move to another subscription.

[image]

**WAY - 2** Deploy the ARM template of your logic app to another Subscription.

**Step-1**

Navigate to the Export template and click deploy

[image]

**Step-2**

Change the subscription Id of your connectors then select the subscription and resource group to which you want to deploy.

[image]

Comment: for example I have logic apps in 'A' account and need to clone this logic app to 'B' account. could you please provide the steps

Comment: @AquibJaveed Can you please check the updated answer

Comment: second approach works for me, deployed using ARM templates

Comment: I think the second screenshot in uploaded by mistake. It does not show anything about ARM templates. Can you please update the screenshot to show how to deploy using ARM templates?

Answer (score 0):

You made a comment that you want to **clone** your LogicApp to another subscription/account, if the first answer isn't what you want then you can (in your words) *clone* the app by copying the code view and pasting it into a new LogicApp in the other subscription/account.

[image: Code View]

For example, this is a JSON definition for an extremely basic LogicApp I just created ...

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Text String",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "This is a test"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 12
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

It looks like this ...

[image: Flow]

You can literally take that JSON definition and paste it into any existing LogicApp and it will produce the same flow.